# "esint" integrals with default limits

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

When I'm trying to set a normal volume integral with the [esint package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/esint), it will be generated with the limits set right to it:

[image: Default volume integral with esint]

A corresponding example code for this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
  \[ \oiint_{O(V)} \]
\end{document}
```

What I'd like to archieve is something more like `\oiint\limits_{O(V)}` but without actually typing the limits-command as this should be the default behaviour in my document. The documentation provides no option similiar to the `intlimits` usable with `amsmath`.

Until now I used a really dirty hack with `\re@DeclareMathSymbol`. Is there another way or maybe another package that could help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not a similar package option for `esint`. But you can use the command `\oiintlim` defined as

```
\def\oiintlim{\oiintop\limits}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\def\oiintlim{\oiintop\limits}
\begin{document}
  \[ \oiintlim_{O(V)} \]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

Otherwise, it is very simple to create a new package `extesint` from the existing `esint`.

Save the following as `extesint.sty` where your document is (or somewhere in your TeX root and refresh the database):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{extesint}
\DeclareOption{intlimits}{\let\ilimits@\displaylimits}
\DeclareOption{nointlimits}{\let\ilimits@\nolimits}
\ExecuteOptions{nointlimits}
\ProcessOptions
\def\re@DeclareMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
        \let#1=\undefined
        \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{esint}{m}{n}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'001}
        \def\int{\intop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'003}
        \def\iint{\iintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'005}
        \def\iiint{\iiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'007}
        \def\iiiint{\iiiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\dotsintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'011}
        \def\dotsint{\dotsintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'013}
        \def\oint{\ointop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'015}
        \def\oiint{\oiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sqintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'017}
        \def\sqint{\sqintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'021}
        \def\sqiint{\sqiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\ointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'027}
        \def\ointctrclockwise{\ointctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\ointclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'031}
        \def\ointclockwise{\ointclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varointclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'033}
        \def\varointclockwise{\varointclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'035}
        \def\varointctrclockwise{\varointctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\fintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'037}
        \def\fint{\fintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'041}
        \def\varoiint{\varoiintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\landupintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'043}
        \def\landupint{\landupintop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\landdownintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'045}
        \def\landdownint{\landdownintop\ilimits@}
\endinput
```

Then, the following MWE works as expected

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[intlimits]{extesint}

\begin{document}
\[ \oiint_{O(V)} \]
\end{document}
```

Omitting `intlimits` or using `nointlimits` let it works as `esint`.

Comment: Thank you. I feared, that there wouldn't be a a "ready-to-use" solution. So I will probably use the own package-approach (as updates to esint seem to be very unlikely -- last one was 2005) and also strip unused symbols.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this simple trick to patch \oiint and its other siblings in your preamble:

`\let\oldoiint\oiint

  \renewcommand{\oiint}{\oldoiint\limits}`

Example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{esint} 

\let\oldoiint\oiint
\renewcommand{\oiint}{\oldoiint\limits}

\begin{document}

\[ \oiint_{O(V)}\]%\qquad \oiint\limits_{O(V)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's really a simple-to-use solution. Although I do prefer the own package.

Comment: ...also: As esint overrides **all** integrals from amsmath, it would be no time-saver to overwrite all integrals this way. I only mentioned one as an example, sorry for being unclear.